# Search Bar In a NavigationStack does not fill the entire screen on iPad

Tags: search, navigation, tabs

import SwiftUI

struct SearchView: View {

```
@State private var searchText = ""

@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme 
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      
    }
    .searchable(text: $searchText)
}
```

}

The search bar in the code was only in a part of the iPad screen, rather than the full iPad screen.